# where to put some script to run before VM Suspend?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I have run one shell script before the vm suspend. How to do this? Where to put this shell script so that it will run before the VM suspend .

Answer (score 0):

You can write an script such as :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "before suspend"
########
your commmands
.
.
.
#######
your command that caused suspened your VM
```

Then you need run above command.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put your scripts in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` so that they will be run before suspension. But as the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/systemd-suspend.service.8.html) indicates, there are nicer ways to do this.